# Implicit type conversion in DB/2 inserts?

Tags: db2, type-conversion

We're using SQL Inserts to insert some data via a script into DB/2 tables, e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE TICKETS (TICKETID VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL);
```

On my home installation, this statement works fine (note that I'm using an integer which is autoatically cast into a VarChar):

```
INSERT INTO TICKETS (TICKETID) VALUES (1);
```

while at my customer's site I get a type error.

My question(s):

- Is this behavior version dependent? (I use a DB2 Express V9.7, while the customer has an Enterprise V9.5)
- Is there a config option to change the behavior? (I would like my home install to behave as close as possible as the production environment is going to be.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DB2 9.5 and earlier enforced strong typing.

DB2 9.7 relaxed this requirement, adding implicit casting between data types.  See the documentation: 
[What's new in DB2 V9.7: Implicit casting](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.wn.doc/doc/c0053519.html)

Comment: Thanks, that explains the behaviour I have seen. Any way to change this?